# document.getElementById no ionic

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ionic2

Tenho um aplicativo desenvolvido com ionic 3 e gostaria de saber se esse tipo de implementação deveria funcionar. Tenho um arquivo html com uma div com id = corpoId. E na implementação abro o arquivo e tento escrever nessa div:

```js
const windowPrint = window.open('/android_asset/www/catalogo.html', '_blank');
var textoHtml = '<html>apenas exemplo de html</html>'
windowPrint.document.getElementById('corpoId').innerHTML = textoHtml;
```

Comment: Você que deveria nos dizer se a implementação funcionou! Funcionou, deu erro algum no console?

Comment: não funcionou, não deu erro no console. o arquivo html abre, porém sem a escrita feito no corpoId.

Comment: Do jeito que está aí, você está pegando um id de um método **window.open()**, o certo seria pegar um id de uma página Html, crie uma variável e coloque o caminho da página exemplo: **var url = /android_asset/www/catalogo.html**, aí você faz **window.open(url)** e depois faz **url.getElementById('corpoId').innerHTML = textoHtml**

Comment: não tem como fazer url.getElementById('corpoId').innerHTML

Comment: Pq não? Deu erro, qual?

Comment: nem compila amigo, [ts] Property 'getElementById' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: Mas você está colocando isto dentro de alguma função?

Comment: estou dentro de um método onde eu monto as tags html e jogo em uma variável string e depois chamo essas linhas que mencionei que fazem respectivamente (ou deveriam fazer): abre o arquivo e escreve na div

Comment: Coloca todo esse código aí amigo, pq este erro é de ts não tem relação com o que eu exemplifiquei!

Comment: não tem como funcionar o que você exemplificou, não tem essa propriedade getElementById em url, por isso nem compila....

Comment: Nossa cara, esquece. Realmente não tem como funcionar o que fiz, estou na empresa e trabalhando com Ionic tbm e misturei a pergunta com o trampo aqui.

Comment: Cara pelo que li aqui no método **window.open()** acho que não terá como escrever em um elemento específico, só direto no documento tipo document.write(<p>Conteúdo aqui</p>).

Comment: obrigado por tentar ajudar, acabei conseguindo resolver:
 const tela_impressao = window.open('/android_asset/www/catalogo.html', '_blank');

    var textoHtml = '<div>teste</div>'


      tela_impressao.document.write(textoHtml);
      tela_impressao.window.print();
      tela_impressao.window.close();

Comment: Posta aí como resposta para ajudar outros usuários.

Comment: postei no comentário acima, não era bem isso que eu precisava, mas não sei se tem como fazer de outra forma.